# How to remove a particular div tag and reset its content using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code below contains certain  tags in all four.
Image-1
[image]
here is the code :

```
 <div style='background-color:YellowGreen;height:20px;width:100%;margin-top:15px;font-weight: bold;'>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;Delegate(s) details: </div>
            <div style="border:1px solid black;"><br/>
            <div id="delegates">
            <div id="0">
            &nbsp;&nbsp; Name of the Delegate: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input name='contact_person[]' type='text' size="50" maxlength="50" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Designation:
             <select name='delegate_type_name[]' class='delegate_type'>
             <option value='select'>Select</option>
             <option value='Main'>Main</option>
             </select>
            </div><br/>
            </div>
            <div>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" name="more" value="Add More Delegates" id="add_more" />
            <br />
            <br />
            </div>
            </div>
```

In the above code on line 5 where `<div id="0">` changes to value 1 in script that I mentioned in "add_more"

And the javascript for "add_more" is given below

```
jQuery('#add_more').click(function(){
        var id = jQuery('#delegates > div:last').attr('id');
        var temp = "<div id='"+(parseInt(id)+parseInt('1'))+"'>&nbsp;&nbsp; Name of the Delegate: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' size='50' maxlength='50' name='contact_person[]' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Designation:";
        temp += "<select name='delegate_type_name[]' class='delegate_type additional_delegate'><option value='select'>Select</option><option value='Additional'>Additional</option><option value='Spouse'>Spouse</option></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='button' name='rem' value='Remove' id='remove' /></div><br/>";
        jQuery('#delegates').append(temp);
    });
```

In the javascript code above I have added a remove button in the temp+ variable

```
<input type='button' name='rem' value='Remove' id='remove' />
```

Image-2 shows the remove button every time I click on "Add more Delegates" button.
[image]
In the image-2 I click on Add More Delegates button it shows the "remove" button on the right of drop down select list.

I want a jQuery function for remove button, so that when I click on remove it should remove `<div id="1">` and also reset content before removing the div tag. Below image-3 is the output that I want when I click on remove button.
[image]

code that I tried was this from some reference is this

```
jQuery('#remove').click(function(){
        var id = jQuery('#delegates > div:last').attr('id').remove();
    });
```

but no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: your question makes no sense - it's almost impossible to parse

Comment: I know, images would have being better to understand. @Alnitak - Thanks

Comment: I hope the images might help ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters your markup is a total mess. There is no way you should be using `&nbsp;` for layout purposes. Read up on tableless layouts and css.

The first thing you *need* to change is the id's of your div. An id cannot start with a numeric. I suggest naming the first div `delegate0`. Secondly, you are adding a remove button on every new row with the same `id` - all id's on a page should be unique so i suggest you change this to `class="remove"`.

As for your question, it really boils down to needing to add a jQuery handler to the remove buttons using the `.live`<sup>[docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/)</sup> method.

This is as simple as:

```
jQuery('.remove').live('click',function(){
   $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

Also, you need to keep a running counter of the id of the items added, and increment this every time a new row is added.

```
var nextDelegate = 1;
jQuery('#add_more').click(function(){
   ... your code here
   nextDelegate++;
});
```

Also, I removed the superfluous `<br/>` after each div.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/cb4xQ/

Comment: I wish i added images to make you'll understand. I know this way its quite difficult to understand.

Comment: @leroy - ive upvoted your quesion so you should be able to add images now.

Comment: remove button is not added with same id as I mentioned in my question 'id' value is changed or incremented my "1" every new row that it creates.

Comment: @ jamiec I used the live example code but still remove button click event not workning. Nothing happens even if I click on remove button.

Comment: it is exactly what I wanted but somehow remove button is not working. How come its working fine in live example ..?? I used the same code also changed the div id's that you asked for.

Comment: @leroy - you can see from the live example `nextDelegate` should just be declared outside of any jquery event handler. Also remember that I changes your code so that when a remove button is created its added with a **class** of `remove` not an id. That means that the live handler must be `jQuery('.remove')` instead of `jQuery('#remove')`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't give an element id that is only a number, it must be #mydiv1, #mydiv2 or something similar, i.e. beginning with a letter not a number.

Comment: actually, in HTML5 you _can_ use numbers as element IDs.